# 'New' cannot be used on an interface Error on changing location of TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to change the location of a textbox but it is giving me this error

> 'New' cannot be used on an interface

here is what I did so far

```
TextBox11.Location = New Point(303, 33)
```

Comment: Based on that message, the name `Point` is being interpreted as some interface type, rather than as `System.Drawing.Point`. If you fully qualify the type name that way, does it work then? You should be able to right-click the name and select *Go to definition* and see where the type the compiler is using is defined. If it's your own interface, you should follow convention and name it `IPoint`. If it's from some other library and you can't change it, you'll just have to qualify the name as above, or else import an alias.